# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined at FillInfo()

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

The title pretty much says everything.

I'm making a form that will return your first name and surname with city in a quote using div class = "well". I'm now stuck for some hours now trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script> /* get info from inputs and add it to a quote. */
    function FillInfo(){
        var fname = document.forms ["SIgnUpForm"] ["fname"].value;
        var sname = document.forms ["SIgnUpForm"] ["sname"].value;
        var city = document.forms ["SIgnUpForm"] ["city"].value;

        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =  "Thank you" + " " + fname + " " + sname + "from" + " " + city + "." + " " + "You are now being considered as our next adventurer. Good luck!";
    }
</script>
```

and in body is:

```
<div class="heading2">
    <div class="container2">
        <p>Do you want to travel troughout space? Then fill out our form!</p><br>
        <form name="SignUpForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Last name" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required><br><br>
            <div id="info" class="well"></div>
            <button class="otherpage" onclick="FillInfo();">Submit</button><br><br>
            <a href="Mainpage.html" class="BeginLink">Return</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect it to write down the quote when i click the submit button, yet in return i get this :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined
>       at FillInfo (things i put into inputs name, city)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (things i put into inputs name, city)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [`formData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to get a `form` object, then [`form.get(name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) to get the content.
*It's a more elegant way to get your content.*

I also replaced your `button` with a `input type="button"`, because it caused a refresh of the page.

*note: it doesn't work on IE & safari for iOS*

```js
    function FillInfo(){
     let f = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));

     var fname = f.get("fname");
     var sname = f.get("sname");
     var city = f.get("city");

     document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =  "Thank you" + " " + fname + " " + sname + " from " + " " + city + "." + " " + "You are now being considered as our next adventurer. Good luck!";
    }
```

```html
   <div class="heading2">
        <div class="container2">
            <p>Do you want to travel troughout space? Then fill out our form!</p><br>
            <form name="SignUpForm" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Last name" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required><br><br>
                <div id="info" class="well"></div>
                <input type="button" class="otherpage" onclick="FillInfo();" value="Submit" /><br><br>
                <a href="Mainpage.html" class="BeginLink">Return</a>
            </form>  
       </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just mistyped the form name

Your Html code: SignUpForm

Your Javascript code :SIgnUpForm

I fixed it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why? These questions keep coming up about `undefined` errors in JavaScript when accessing the `DOM`. Please, ensure the `DOM` is ready before accessing it. Just putting your scripts after your html won't assure you of that.

Though the "SIgnUpForm" name will give you errors and is corrected here, it doesn't solve the entire problem. Different processor and network speeds and browser mechanisms may result in you having an `undefined` property error if you don't ensure the Document Object Model (DOM) is ready before you access elements in the html document.

```
<script> /* get info from inputs and add it to a quote. */
    window.onload = function () {
        function FillInfo(){
            var fname = document.forms ["SignUpForm"] ["fname"].value;
            var sname = document.forms ["SignUpForm"] ["sname"].value;
            var city = document.forms ["SignUpForm"] ["city"].value;


            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =  "Thank you" + " " + fname + " " + sname + "from" + " " + city + "." + " " + "You are now being considered as our next adventurer. Good luck!";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also, consider using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` method for cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

I just modify code, it's working in all browsers:

```
    <script> /* get info from inputs and add it to a quote. */
    function FillInfo(){
    let form = document.querySelector('form');

     var fname = form.elements["fname"];
     var sname = form.elements["sname"];
     var city = form.elements["city"];

     document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =  "Thank you" + " " + fname.value + " " + sname.value + " from " + " " + city.value + "." + " " + "You are now being considered as our next adventurer. Good luck!";
      return false;
    }
</script>

<div class="heading2">
    <div class="container2">
        <p>Do you want to travel troughout space? Then fill out our form!</p><br>
        <form name="SignUpForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Last name" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required><br><br>
            <div id="info" class="well"></div>
            <button class="otherpage" type="button" onclick="FillInfo();">Submit</button><br><br>
            <a href="Mainpage.html" class="BeginLink">Return</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```